# My pyglet application cant show other slides

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm new to pyglet, but have needed to learn it quickly in order to complete a school project. Basically, I have my first slide with the images menu and preview on it, and a second slide that has the end_screen image on it. The showing of the first slide works just fine, though the program wont let me transition into the second slide when I press a key. No Error message, It just doesnt do anything when I try to draw the second slide.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
import time
slide = 1
preview_image = pyglet.image.load('untitled (3).jpg')
menu_image = pyglet.image.load('untitled (4).jpg')
end_screen_image = pyglet.image.load('untitled (5).jpg')
preview = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(preview_image, x=0, y=0)
menu = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(menu_image, x=540, y=0)
end_screen = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(end_screen_image, x=270, y=0)
window = pyglet.window.Window(1180, 630)
def update():
    global menu
    global window
    global preview
    global end_screen
    global slide
    if slide == 1:
        window.clear()
        preview.draw()
        menu.draw()
    elif slide == 2:
        window.clear()
        end_screen.draw()
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    global slide
    slide = 2
    update()
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    preview.draw()
    menu.draw()
pyglet.app.run()
```

For some reason it just wont work. I've tried different kinds of update functioons but none of them worked either. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue here is the concept of `update` and how you'd normally expect code to execute.
I'm guessing you're used to code being called *as you write it*, meaning that you think *"If I press a button, I want `update()` to be called instead"*. And that's true, partially.

The problem you're experiencing is that Pyglet is trying to render things as fast as possible, and it does so by calling `on_draw()` as often as needed. So when you execute `update()` - a fraction of a second later `on_draw()` will be called again, and again.. and again. And the first line you have in `on_draw` is `window.clear()` - which clears the window and any changes made in `update()`. Hopefully that makes sense.

Instead, you probably want your "which thing am i showing"-logic in the `on_draw` every render. Altho this will be pretty slow, hopefully this convey the logic of how the automatic rendering process works and why your logic from school assignments doesn't necessarily translate well into projects where there's "background tasks" running.

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key
import time

preview = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('untitled (3).jpg'), x=0, y=0)
menu = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('untitled (4).jpg'), x=540, y=0)
end_screen = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.load('untitled (5).jpg'), x=270, y=0)
window = pyglet.window.Window(1180, 630)

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    global slide
    slide = 2

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    if slide == 1:
        window.clear()
        preview.draw()
        menu.draw()
    elif slide == 2:
        window.clear()
        end_screen.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Oh and btw, no need for `global` on variables in functions like your `update()` function. Unless you assign something to variables (`menu = ...`) they're going to be global by default *(For instance, see in `on_key_press` where you update `slide` with `slide = 2`, in those cases you need to globalize first)*. Just a friendly reminder how global scope works in Python and it's functions - giving you some more wiggle room to write less code and achieve the same thing. So remember, `=` means you need to make them global, otherwise don't bother :)

I also made the code a bit "smaller", since you're not using `preview_image` i went ahead and passed the image-loading-result straight into `Sprite()` for `preview` for instance, saving 3 lines of code making it arguably slightly less code and thus more readable. It's a matter of taste tho, can revert it if you feel like it.

Comment: thank you torxed! The code worked perfectly, and you saved me from not having my assignment due on time. You truly are a great person for taking the time to answer this. Also, thanks for suggesting the way to shorten my code. I picked up the bad way to do it from a pyglet tutorial I watched, but now I see the way you did it is much better. You are a legend!

Comment: @Rotten_soap You're welcome. Just a quick reminder that we're not usually keen on helping with school assignments. But this didn't look like a general assignment given by a teacher to teach a point so I helped out. Also, don't forget to mark the question as solved so it doesn't add to the "unanswered" pile :)